# Mac OS X 10.10 - Missing 'posix_memalign'? - error: implicit declaration of function 'posix_memalign'

Tags: c++, c, macos, posix

I'm trying to compile a project on my Mac with OS X 10.10 and I am getting this error

```
error: implicit declaration of function 'posix_memalign' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
```

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: What about the code?

Comment: Looks like a missing `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: I tried including it at the top of the source file. It did not work.

I am trying to  cross-compile nginx for android by using this project:

https://bitbucket.org/ntakimura/android-nginx/